# Change webform error status message

Tags: forms, webforms, 10, status-messages

I'm working on making my webform on my site (D10) completely accessible. When I'm submitting my form empty I get a status message because I have two required fields. The message is:

```
2 errors have been found:
Name,
Email
```

Where the field names are links to the fields. For better accessibility I want to change the output of this error to something like:

```
2 errors have been found sending the form:
Field name can't be empty,
Field Email can't be empty
```

I've found options for change the message using a `hook_form_alter`. But this way I have to write a custom validation. The only thing I want is change the text. I also found the `hook_preprocess_status_messages` but this already had the message in markup so not easy to change. Is there a solid and easy way to change the text of the messages only?

Comment: Patch webform and share this improvement in a webform issue.

Comment: Thanks great suggestion, I will...have any idea where I can find this messages? I already searched for it but couldn't find it. I was able to find the first line @ errors have been found: but not the links to the fields.